# python program syntax error on `else:`

Tags: python

when I run my program which finds the inverse permutation of numbers, it returns me with the follow error:

```
python inverse_permutation.py 1 2 3 4 5
  File "inverse_permutation.py", line 18
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Prior to asking this question I tried looking at similar posts, but could not find a solution to my specific problem. Here is my code:

```
import stdarray
import stdio
import sys

q = input().split()
for i in range(len(q)):
    q[i] = int(q[i])
l = len(q)
s = int((l*(l+1))/2-(l))
s2 = 0
b = [0 for i in range(l)]
for i in range(l):
    s2 = s2+q[i]
if(s == s2):
    for i in range(l):
        b[q[i]] = i
print(b)
else:
    print('Not a permutation')
```

Comment: indent your print(b)

Comment: You forgot to indent the `print`.

Comment: VTC as typo, because it's obvious OP meant to have `print(b)` indented.

Answer (score 0):

if should be followed by else, but you have put the print statement between if and else, you can do something like this

```
import stdarray
import stdio
import sys

q = input().split()
for i in range(len(q)):
    q[i] = int(q[i])
l = len(q)
s = int((l*(l+1))/2-(l))
s2 = 0
b = [0 for i in range(l)]
for i in range(l):
    s2 = s2+q[i]
if(s == s2):
    for i in range(l):
        b[q[i]] = i
else:
    print('Not a permutation')

print(b)
```